# Set cookies for all browsers

Tags: c#, google-chrome, firefox, cookies, browser

I want to set a domain-specific cookies for FireFox and Chrome, something equivalent to `InternetSetCookie()` API, which takes a URL and a cookie name and value and sets it for all browsers. I have already checked that `InternetSetCookie()` only works for IE. I'm using C# + .NET 4.0 (desktop app) if that is important.

(just to add some clarification, this is kind of a password manager app that stores user's login/password info for his favorite websites and upon clicking a button in the app, it launches user's default browser, goes to login page of that website, submits username/password in POST fields and simply takes user to his home page. Some of these websites send cookies in response to the login page request that I then need to set before making the subsequent login request).

Comment: Check this for reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751813/cookies-with-and-without-the-domain-specified-browser-inconsistency